# Remove Ubuntu from stand-alone hard drive. Format drive

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, hard-drive, live-cd

I guess that I have no other choice than to add to this question, as seth saw fit to delete the question I thought I was asking as a new question. But whatever. I have a dead computer thanks to my having installed it in the first place. It will not boot either or any hard drives, and gives me the same answer

```
Error No such device
3dddc179-e42e-4666-8ff3-00566a57908a
Entering rescue mode
```

grub rescue> all it does is flash the cursor nothing more from there.

My computer is useless as is. I can not load either OS, and have no idea how to fix it, short of taking it to a shop. I don't understand, how to fix it, if I can't even open it up. All i want is a straightforward answer on how to fix the problem. As this is the only means I have of contacting anybody on how to fix the problem. which I assume is in the BIOS setup. with grub. I need answers, not negative stuff like you need to use the forum more so that you have more privileges. If anybody really know how I can get my computer back to having just Windows 7 and my other hard drive formatted again so I can start over. Without ubuntu at least until I can figure out how to put the live CDs on a USB flash drive. And one then in the try mode, instead of the install mode as that is all I am given on the CD's I've got now.

---

I am either dumb as a rock, or I am brain dead. I have tried and tried to figure out all the in's and out's of down loading Live CD's and to boot them so I can check them out before installing. I thought I had downloaded the live CD program that would let me do that. For ubuntu, mint, and zorin. I guess that I downloaded the full version of all three.

I don't know if there are individual downloads for the Live CD programs for those OS's as well as full CDs? Anyway, I got the CD to open, their was no option to install or open live. I ended up hitting the Install. And sent it to a blank stand alone hard drive. It installed, but I am not sure how to open it. Anyway I tried to format the drive, and it says that it is now write protected.

I would really like to remove everything from that disk, starting over by trying each system, before installing one or more of them on that hard drive. It is 1.5TB. Any help you can provide is welcome. And if you can explain exactly how to download and burn the correct programs for a live CD so I can test them out. I have read page after page from Linux about all these subjects and the more I read the worse it gets. I need a simple how to that I can use for each system, without having to download fifteen different things to do this that or the other thing.

I was under the belief that Linux was easy to use. That may be once I get it on the computer. Its getting there that has confused me. Please somebody help.

Comment: If you are using Windows, have you tried using MiniTool Partition Wizard to format the drive? http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

Comment: I have two internal hard drives on this computer. Win 7 i son one, and I guess I installed ubuntu on the other. But I would like to clear and format the one with ubuntu. And download and open the Live CD or USB so I can check them out first before installing them onto the second drive. I was trying to divide that drive into thirds. But I guess I screwed that up also.

Comment: @magicgraywolf I know it's trivial, but have you tried setting the boot order to the windows drive?

Answer (score 0):

I always use liveUSBs because they are far, far faster.  A liveCD likely will not give you a good experience.

This is where you can download Ubuntu.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

This is how you can turn any flash drive into a liveUSB using the downloaded .iso.  If you need to use a CD, the link should be on this page as well.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried making a Live USB for all three programs, it does not to seem to be working, or I've not figured it out.